# How to draw a line (path, svg) between two elements that aren't always rectangular

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm making a diagramming library in Blazor which uses HTML nodes and SVG links. I am wondering how can I draw links between two nodes when they aren't always rectangular.

All the solutions I find are based on nodes that are rectangles/squares, where it's easy to draw a link on the borders (or even the center, but only works for direct links).

But what about nodes that have custom stuff in them that makes them non rectangular, for example a div with `border-radius: 50%`?

One possible solution is to draw the lines from/to the center of the elements, but that would only work with simple lines, curved lines would look weird.

In this example:
[image]

How does arrow position get calculated?

Comment: Most drawing programs have various predefined connection points on the icons i.e. each HTML node would have metadata which would tell the program drawing the lines where to start/end them.

Comment: My library does have the notion of "ports", but when I see other libraries I find them drawing links dynamically without needing predefined ports (e.g. JointJS), maybe I'm mistaken

Comment: the contact points are those where the distance is the shortest between the 2 elements

Comment: I added an example. @MisterJojo how do you get these "contact points"

Comment: in your example the target point corresponds to the geometric center, but it stops at the meeting of the border, so you must calculate this crossing point

Comment: I believe that's only possible for SVG nodes right? What about my use case (html nodes)

Comment: anyway it remains math, each line is representable by an equation, the crossing point corresponds to the only point which solves the 2 equations => System of two equations with two unknowns

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an container, width and height of the container, then inside the container find the x / y point of the element that you want to connect and draw a line to the next elements x / y point, the x/y points can be calculated using x,y,w,h of the element, for an example x:100 y:100 w:100 h:100 the center point sits at x:150, y:150  x = x + ( w / 2 ), y = y + ( h / 2 ).. using math just calculate the point of connection of the elements, the complexity of math for calculating the connection point is in the shape of the element, for each different shape you need a different calculation metod if not in center